# Selenium Web Driver Element not visibe exception

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium, webdriver

My Element looks something like:

`/html/body/div/div[3]/form/table/tbody/tr/td/**div[2**]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input`

```
 <input type="password" name="0.2.1.3.3.6.5.1.2.1.1" maxlength="9">
```

I have tried XPath and CSS selectors using Javascript in WebDriver, yet I am unable to locate this element.

There is a script tag between the bolded div[2] tag, is it possible that's causing issues?

Please help!!

Comment: I do not believe that the script tag is causing it.  What selectors have you tried, and are you getting ElementNotFoundExceptions?

Comment: I have tried xpath, css selector with javascript as well. I have to type a text is this particular field. I used JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('0.2.1.3.3.6.5.1.2.1.1')[0].setAttribute('type', '333444555');");....this time the test passed but there was no text typed into the field

Comment: We will need some basic HTML to reproduce the issue. Please post the exact code you are using, and the exact full error you are getting. Please also post your versions and browser versions. Finally, please ensure there are no IFrames.

Comment: Code is
<div id="outerDiv" style="...">
<script type="">
<form action="/cgi-bin/WebObjects.exe/QA2_OO_MON.woa/..." name="FORM_NAME" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="TAB_INDEX" value="0">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="ersTabControlDivId">
<script language="javascript">
<div id="_ersEmployeeSetupWizard" >
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table width="50%" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">
<td width="20%">
<input type="password" name="0.2.1.3.3.6.5.1.2.1.1" maxlength="9">

Comment: Earlier I was using xpath, css selector and ByName selectors, however everytime I got element not visible exception

Now I am using 


WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='0.2.1.3.3.6.5.1.2.1.1']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element3);

and the test passes.

However I am not sure how to type text in this field. I think setAttribute can be used here but I am not sure how to use it. Also is there a way sendKeys can be used to type text in this field

Comment: I have sort of resolved the issue, however now I am stuck with new one mentioned above (how to type in the field). I am using FireFox 23 and there are no Iframes in the application

Answer (score 0):

Your title says that you are getting an Element not visible exception...either the selector is wrong (as in, you're selecting a similar element that isn't visible on the page), or you need to wait for it to be visible with

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))
```

Comment: earlier I was getting this, however when I used WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='0.2.1.3.3.6.5.1.2.1.1']")); ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element3); the test passed...now I have to type some text in this field and I am not sure how to use setAttribute method or sendKeys

Comment: Execute a script of `arguments[0].type("");`

Comment: This fails. Failure Trace...arguments[0].type(""); is not a function

Comment: ....it needs to be in your JavascriptExecutor....  You should look up JavascriptExcecutor, and learn what that code is doing.

Comment: WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='0.2.1.3.3.6.5.1.2.1.1']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].type('333444555');", element3); this piece is failing

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS Selector `css=input[type='password'][maxlength='9']` can be used. Please Let Me Know is this CSS Selector Working or Not.